# BigCommerce webhook not firing

Tags: bigcommerce, webhooks

I was able to successfully set up a webhook for my BigCommerce store.  However, I am not receiving any requests from the store.

When I created the webhook, I received this response, which makes me think it worked correctly:

```
{
"id": 437,
"client_id": "dagb0rxpdd2o3znkebn5pydxj4ztcq8",
"store_hash": "xxxxxx",
"scope": "store/product/updated",
"destination": "https://my-domain.com/index.php/webhooks/product_updated/",
"headers": null,
"is_active": true,
"created_at": 1403545148,
"updated_at": 1403545148
}
```

Now, when I go into my store, edit a product, and save, I am not getting any requests to my destination url.  I checked the apache ssl access logs and do not see any requests from BigCommerce. I tested the webhook destination by issuing my own POST request to my destination URL, and that works correctly, so it seems that something is causing the webhook requests not to be sent from BigCommerce to my server.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

It'll be one of these...

~ OAuth integration for the store is required to webhooks to fire.

~ A valid SSL Certificate from a known CA (not self signed!) is required for receiving fired webhooks.

I understand it's misleading as everything (OAuth + Creating webhooks) is happy with self signed, just when using them it requires valid cert.

Comment: As far as I know, the two points you mentioned are done correctly. The SSL Certificate is not self-signed, it's from a CA. I confirm this by visiting the webhook URL in a browser, which correctly recognizes the certificate and doesn't issue a browser warning. The certificate is from StartSSL. Should that be OK?  Also, when you say that OAuth integration is required for the store, what do you mean by that? Doesn't the fact that I created the webhook in the first place confirm that OAuth integration is working?

Comment: Odd, can you list the callbacks to check it is still active as eventually it deactivates itself after many failures. That SLL should be fine, assume your browser accepts it and is configured correctly. It you page provided a status code response? Also it can take a minute for webhooks to be active. Also whilst testing I advise (like i did) to use a /* endpoint so you capture more than just updates.

Comment: GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/hooks/{id} should check if it's still active

Comment: Actually no, for some reason I can't list webhooks. Maybe that is part of the issue? To create the webhook I sent a POST request to the /hooks endpoint which included the `X-Auth-Token` and `X-Auth-Client` headers. When I hit the same endpoint, with the same headers, with a GET request, I receive a 401 Unauthorized error. Could this be part of the problem? Do you have any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: I am, but I'm actually just using this tool to quickly test the requests:  http://www.hurl.it/ - Like I said, it worked correctly to create the webhook, so I'm pretty confident the tool works correctly.

Comment: I am using this pull req https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/pull/101 and this pull req https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/pull/88 together which work a treat. Quick and easy for you. (these are alongside the master tree too obviously). Hope this helps - good luck

Comment: I used the pulls you mentioned but am still having no luck. When I list the hooks saved to my store, I see the ones I created, and `is_active = 1`. I have no idea why it's not working.

Comment: Strange, could be a bug their end. Have you checked your applications permissions to see if you have read access on this endpoint?

Comment: Yea, I have "modify" access set for all scopes.  Is that what you mean?  I don't see what else it could be besides a bug on their end.  I sent a support ticket in 4 days ago and am yet to receive any sort of response. Thanks a lot for the help and if you have any other ideas I'm all ears.

Comment: Do you have a working webhook? If so, is there any chance you can tell me what the "headers" field says if you perform a GET request to view a working hook? When I do a GET request to list my hooks, all of them have `"headers":null`. I'm wondering if that could be causing the issue.

Comment: My headers are not ```null``` but I experience the same problem. I've created webHook, I can list webhooks, but do not receive any requests from bigCommerce. I also purchased SSL certificate.

Comment: Came here looking for the answer to missing webhook events as well- I still can't get BigCommerce webhooks to fire any way I can detect them. However I suspect the 401 error on the get request is a bad error message- if your tool is similar to CURL it's most likely you need to set a header on the get request to accept JSON: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170326/valid-bigcommerce-auth-token-triggers-authorization-error-getting-webhooks/25797082#25797082